# Unable to compile Dropwizard application using DataSourceFactory

Tags: java, gradle, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm trying to follow the [Dropwizard documentation for working with JDBI3](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/jdbi3.html). I'm using Gradle as the build tool.

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    ...
}

jar {
    ...
}

...

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def dropwizardVersion = "2.0.10"

...

dependencies {
    testCompile group: "junit", name: "junit", version: "4.12"

    implementation "io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:${dropwizardVersion}"

    ...
}
```

According to the documentation, my `Configuration` class requires an instance of a `DataSourceFactory`, but that class doesn't seem to exist? In fact, it seems like the `io.dropwizard.db` module doesn't exist at all.

What needs to be added or changed to get this to compile?

Comment: Check the `dropwizard-example` project: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/pom.xml#L65 . You need ``dropwizard-migrations` and (`dropwizard-jdbi3` or `dropwizard-hibernate`).

Comment: Seems like adding the `dropwizard-migrations` module is key, this worked for me! If you want to post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks. No need. IMO this kind of questions shouldn't exist.